# Is it possible to send a cookie with a SMSMessage using the Twilio-csharp / TwilioRestClient?

Tags: twilio, restsharp

I am creating outbound SMS communication and need to set a cookie so I can track the conversation thread.  I'm using the Twilio-charp client and did not see a way to set a cookie or and http header.  Is this possible or do I need to pursue a different route?

**Edit:**

I need to elucidate here.  In my scenario I need to set a cookie with a transaction id that needs to included in the originating outbound message.  For example I will be creating an SMS message that will request a response from the user:  "Text (1) to approve, (2) to decline".

The Twilio sample code details a page that receives a message, checks for a cookie, then creates one if it does not already exist.  In my scenario I need the cookie to be in the outbound message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted support at Twilio and they stated that cookies can not be sent with their REST API.  Cookies can be exchanged from the response endpoint that you create where you set the http header.

This means that you must wait for the user to reply to your first message before you can insert cookies to the http headers.

Comment: Yes. You could attach a special query parameter to the URL that Twilio requests, like http://myexample.com?user=david. Twilio would request this URL and you could read the query parameter out of the HTTP request at that point.

Comment: @KevinBurke, could you please explain it in more details? I cannot find documentation about a "special query parameter".

Comment: @KevinBurke I like your answer can you elaborate on it or point me to documentation please.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely set a cookie to track the conversation thread. Details and sample code can be found here under Twilio's .NET (C#) quickstarts: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/tracking-conversations

Comment: Thanks the response.  The sample code listed works for the inbound communication to my app.  Reading my question I wasn't clear.  I need to set the cookie on the first outbound message so when it comes back the app can associate the user response with the original transaction.